# Ansible loop : How can I loop through the array using with_sequence for index

Tags: arrays, loops, ansible, .when, ansible-template

I have multiple arrays with same length. I need to loop through the length and call the elements. I tried the below one and failed. Can you please let me know where I did wrong in this. Or is there any better approach to loop through array elements.

```
  tasks:
  - name: Set facts
    set_fact:
      SERIAL_NUMBER: ['2342', '4455', '5643']
      PASSWORD: ['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz']
      EXP_DATE: ['06-10-18', '07-01-19', '06-01-18']
      LICENSE_TYPE: "evaluation"

 - name: Execute the script to apply evaluation license
    lineinfile:
      dest: "/root/test.txt"
      line: "{{ SERIAL_NUMBER[{{ item }}] }} {{ PASSWORD[{{ item }}] }} {{ EXP_DATE[{{ item }}] }}"
      create: yes
    with_sequence: start=0 end={{ SERIAL_NUMBER|length }}
    when: "{{ LICENSE_TYPE }}" == "evaluation"
```

I even tried the below approach in place of line:. But no luck.

```
line: "{{ SERIAL_NUMBER[item]int % SERIAL_NUMBER|length }} {{ PASSWORD[item]int % PASSWORD|length }} {{ EXP_DATE[item]int % EXP_DATE|length }}"
```

I see 2 issues here.

1. The array element calling with flower braces inside flower braces {{ {{ }} }}.
2. The second is using "when" in this case.

Thank you.

Comment: Error message: `TASK [Execute the script to apply evaluation license] ********************************************************************************************
fatal: [10.75.44.199]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'. String: {{ SERIAL_NUMBER[{{ item }}] }}"}`

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `query` function with `together` to get in the same loop iteration the 1st element from each array.

the when syntax should be:

```
when: LICENSE_TYPE == "evaluation"
```

please check the below task (with `debug` module to just demonstrate the data `query` supplies to the loop):

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:

  tasks:
    - name: Set facts
      set_fact:
        SERIAL_NUMBER: ['2342', '4455', '5643']
        PASSWORD: ['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz']
        EXP_DATE: ['06-10-18', '07-01-19', '06-01-18']
        LICENSE_TYPE: "evaluation"


    - name: Execute the script to apply evaluation license
      debug:
        msg: "SERIAL_NUMBER: {{ item[0] }}, PASSWORD: {{ item[1] }}, EXP_DATE: {{ item[2] }}"
      when: LICENSE_TYPE == "evaluation"
      loop: "{{ query('together', SERIAL_NUMBER, PASSWORD, EXP_DATE) }}"
```

output:

```
PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Set facts] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Execute the script to apply evaluation license] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "SERIAL_NUMBER: 2342, PASSWORD: xxx, EXP_DATE: 06-10-18"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "SERIAL_NUMBER: 4455, PASSWORD: yyy, EXP_DATE: 07-01-19"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "SERIAL_NUMBER: 5643, PASSWORD: zzz, EXP_DATE: 06-01-18"
}

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost
```

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. good luck

```
  tasks:
  - name: Set facts
    set_fact:
      SERIAL_NUMBER: ['2342', '4455', '5643']
      PASSWORD: ['xxx', 'yyy', 'zzz']
      EXP_DATE: ['06-10-18', '07-01-19', '06-01-18']
      LICENSE_TYPE: "evaluation"

 - name: Execute the script to apply evaluation license
    lineinfile:
      dest: "/root/test.txt"
      line: "{{ SERIAL_NUMBER[index] }} {{ PASSWORD[index] }} {{ EXP_DATE[index] }}"
      create: yes
    loop: "{{ SERIAL_NUMBER|flatten(levels=1) }}"
    loop_control:
      index_var: index
    when: "{{ LICENSE_TYPE }}" == "evaluation"
```

Comment: You should add an explanation for your code. It can be brief.